# How to reuse cached ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I am quite new to the whole cache thing, and I am wondering how you would reuse the response of an ajax call in jQuery. From the docs(http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) I read, that cache is standard set to `true`, so I am wondering, when the user redirects to another page, how would I access that same response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make the request using the same code as you used before.

The browser will fetch it from its cache, make a fresh request to the server, or make an `If-Modified-Since` request as per the cache control headers in the original response.

Comment: So the browser knows in the moment when I make the ajax call "the client already requested this file, so i will return this, let's say, json"?

Comment: Yes. That's part of the point of URLs. They identify such things.

Comment: Great, thanks for the insight. Can't accept your answer just now, in 10 minutes I will.